# The dimension and basis of the set $F = \{(a+3b,a-b,2a-b,4b)| a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $F = \{(a+3b,a-b,2a-b,4b)| a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$
>
> 1. Show that F is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$;
> 2. Find a basis for F;
> 3. Find the dimension of F.

I have part A completed and showed that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but am struggling with the basis portion of the question (number 2).

Comment: Hint: Note that any element of $F$ is a linear combination of $(1,1,2,0)$ and $(3,-1,-1,4)$.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You should try and explain which parts are giving you trouble. Otherwise it looks a lot like you want somebody to do your linear algebra assignment. André already gave you a useful hint. Why don't you work on that and report what you can do with the hint! It may happen that before you are done squeezing the last drop out of that hint the question will have been put on hold. That is the regulars way of telling you that you should improve the question. Frankly, it doesn't look good at the moment. Should that happen it's not the end. Just edit in your own work, and it will be "reopened".

Comment: I have part A completed and showed that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but am struggling with the basis portion of the question

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you could define this equivalently as follows. Let $f$ be the following  function:
$$f(a,b)=(a+3b,a-b,2a-b,4b).$$
This forms a bijective *linear* map from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $F$. Find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is its image under $f$?